# How much total supply should I have to a newly created token?

Tags: tokens, bsc, pancakeswap, binance

I've created a BEP20 token and I can't figure out some steps.

1. The total supply? How big the number must be?

Comment: There is no answer to that question. It entirely depends of your business model. What is the token used for? Why would someone purchase it?

Comment: I just want to learn about these issues, I will appreciate if someone explain and answer my questions.